# is there a mathematical way to go about this coding question?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, python

i have the following python code(assume `x` is already defined as an integer):

```
numList=[] #creates a list that is empty
for i in range(x,-1,-1): #loops through from i=x to i=0, decreasing one each iteration
    if i%5==1: #if i mod 5 is 1...
        numList.pop(1) #remove the second item from the list
    elif i%5==4: # if i mod 5 is 4...
        numList.pop(-1) #remove the last item from the list
    else: #if i mod 5 is not 1 or 4...
        numList.append(i) #add i to the list
print(numList) #prints out the list
```

i am given that the output is `[23, 8, 7, 3, 2, 0]`(hopefully its clear what this means). i am tasked to find the possible values for `x`. is there some logical/mathematical way i can go about this without resorting to guess and check? i tried going "backwards" from the end result but it got too convoluted very quickly.

i have also tried setting x to 5a+2, 5a+3, and 5a (we dont consider 5a+1 and 5a+4 because that will terminate the code prematurely) because they give different values mod 5, but i cant seem to get anywhere with that as well.

Comment: What do `pop(1)` and `pop(-1)` do if the list is empty or there is no second element?

Comment: It destroys your computer

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen the code will terminate and will not be ran successfully. importantly, the print statement will never be ran and therefore the code will not output anything.

Comment: i also want to clarify that im not allowed to run any code for this question. so dont answer with more code; instead, i want a more mathematical/logical answer

Comment: Notice that for every five numbers, which can be divided into 0,1,2,3,4 mod 5, you remove an element at 1 mod 5 as well as 4 mod 5, and you add an element at 0, 2, 3 mod 5. Thus there is a net gain of 1 every five numbers. Since the length of your output is 6, you would logically try about starting at 30. From there, you might try numbers in the range of 10 below and above it, giving you a solution via educated guessing.

Comment: @Stacker that still is a little too "guess and check" for my tastes if you know what i mean but i guess its the best we can do, unless if someone has a different approach that could potentially shave off some guess and check work.

Comment: Notice that x must be at least 23. And cannot be too large otherwise there will be too many elements. It cannot be 7*5=35 or greater. Now I suggest going through what happens at 23,24,25,26,27 to see if there is anything you can find out.

Answer (score 1):

At least roughly, every consecutive five rounds pop two and append three, so net append 1. For six entries you will need 30-ish rounds (and of course certainly you appended 23 at some point.

Also note that the first term will not change any more after a few rounds.

---

After clarification of undefined behaviour when `pop`ing an illegal position:

Write $x=5m+r$ where $m,n\in\Bbb N_0$ asn $r<5$. As we never insert a number $>x$ into the list, we must have $x\ge 23$ and so $m\ge4$.

If $r=0$, the first few rounds produce
$$[]\to [5m]\to [] \to [5m-2]\to [5m-2,5m-3]\to [5m-2]\to [5m-2,5m-5] $$
and after this, the length will always be $\ge2$ when a `pop` is made. It follows that the first term $5m-2$ will stay there until the end. As thsi must be $=23$, we conclude $m=5$ and $x=25$.

If $r=1$, already the first round fails as `pop(1)` from an empty list fails.

If $r=2$, we fail in the second round:
$$ []\to[5m+2]\stackrel{\text{pop}(1)}\longrightarrow ??$$

If $r=3$,
$$ []\to [5m+3]\to[5m+3,5m+2]\to[5m+3]\to\ldots$$
which is in fact the sequence belonging to $x+2$ (see the case $r=0$ above) with the first two rounds dropped. It follows that $x=23$ is also a solution if $x=25$ is.

If $r=4$, we fail immeditely with an illegal `pop(-1)`.

IN summary, there are two possibilities

1. Both $x=25$ and $x=23$ are solutions
2. There is no solution.

So let's play through $x=23$:
$$[]\to[23]\to[23,22]\to[23]\to [23,20]\to[23]\to\\
\to[23,18]\to[23,18,17]\to[23,17]\to [23,17,15]\to[23,17]\to\\
\to[23,17,13]\to[23,17,13,12]\to[23,13,12]\to[23,13,12,10]\to[23,13,12]\to\\
\to[23,13,12,8]\to[23,13,12,8,7]\to[23,12,8,7]\to[23,12,8,7,5]\to\\\to[23,12,8,7]\to[23,12,8,7,3]\to[23,12,8,7,3,2]\to[23,8,7,3,2]\to\\\to[23,8,7,3,2,0]$$
Yay!

Answer (score 0):

Use a brute force method.

```
z=numeric(0)
for (x in 0:1000) {
y=numeric(0)
for (i in x:0) {
  if (i%%5==1) {
    y=y[-2]
  } else if (i%%5==4) {
    y=y[-length(y)]   
  } else {
    y=append(y, i)
  }
}
if (identical(c(23, 8, 7, 3, 2, 0), y)) {
  z=append(z, x)
}
}
```

The answers are

```
> print(z)
[1] 23 24 25 26
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i want to clarify that im not allowed to run any code for this question.